# Azure WindowsPushMessage Xml Payload Format

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

On my Azure Mobile Service, I am sending a Push Notification to a Windows Phone 8.1 with the following code:

```
WindowsPushMessage message = new WindowsPushMessage();
message.XmlPayload = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" +
    @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01"">" +
    @"<text id=""1"">" + pushString + @"</text>" +
    @"</binding></visual></toast>";
try
{
    var result = await Services.Push.SendAsync(message);
    Services.Log.Info(pushString);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Services.Log.Error(ex.Message, null, "Push.SendAsync Error");
}
```

I want to change the format of the Notification, Though, and all I can seem to find are these formats:

```
WindowsPushMessage message = new WindowsPushMessage();
message.XmlPayload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                "<wp:Toast>" +
                "<wp:Text1>Yo Dawg</wp:Text1>" +
                "</wp:Toast> " +
                "</wp:Notification>";

WindowsPushMessage message = new WindowsPushMessage();
message.XmlPayload ="<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                    "<wp:Toast>" +
                    "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
                    "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
                    "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" +
                    "</wp:Toast> " +
                    "</wp:Notification>";
```

But these formats do not work correctly with WindowsPushMessage payload. I receive this error for either one of the them:

```
The payload is not in accepted XML format. The first node should be Badge/Tile/Toast. If want to send raw notification, please set header to wns/raw.
```

Can anyone tell me what the correct format would be?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
message.XmlPayload = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" +
    @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastNewPayload"">" +
    @"<text id=""1"">" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString()+ @"</text>" +
    @"<text id=""2"">" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + @"</text>" +
    @"<text id=""3"">/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</text>" +
    @"</binding></visual></toast>";
```

See the following doc: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-templates/

Comment: The phone app is able to receive this format, but it doesn't show any of the text or allow me to navigate to the page. It just says New Notification...